# Option or Gem to see Controller and Views for a page when viewing on local server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

is there an option or gem that will show me exactly which controller served which views to create the current page I'm looking at, as well as parameters and what not, in some sort of dev console.  This would be really helpful for exploring more complex applications that I don't have experience with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your default layout and you will see the controller and the action and the parameters for each page

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

You might have to add some css to make it look good

Comment: Agreed.  I have the following in layouts/application.html.erb.  That is the base of every page.  You can add many variables within debug to show information when you are in development.  As follows:   <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= debug(request.class) if Rails.env.development? %>, for example

Answer (score 0):

start with tailing your log file `tail -f log/development.log`

Rack Mini Profiler is nice:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-mini-profiler
- https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler

New Relic

- https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode
- https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-installation